# How convert userInput to a number and use that number to create a desired outcome with javascript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, user-input, repeat

I very new to javascript and I am trying to print out a chessboard with "#" symbols. I would like to ask the user "How wide do you want your chessboard to be?" When the user inputs their desired number, I want to convert this string to a number so that I can use it to create the board. For example if the user inputs= 8, the console will print a pattern like so (8x8):

```
# # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # #
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var userInput = prompt("How wide do you want your chessboard to be?")

var userInput = Number(userInput)

var string1 = Array(userInput).join(" #")
var string2 = Array(userInput).join("# ")
var newline = "\n"
var counter = 0.5

var chessboard = function () {
    console.log(string1 + newline + string2);
};

while (counter <= userInput/2) {
    console.log(chessboard);
    counter++
};
```

Comment: What specifically is your question here?

Comment: Arun helped with part of the problem. I need to repeat "chessboard" userInput/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are calling `chessboard`, you are passing a function reference to `console.log()`, so it will log the function.

Since your `chessboard` method prints the string, just call the `chessboard` method like

```
while (counter <= userInput/2) {
    chessboard();
    counter++
};
```

But there are a logical issue here, what will happen if the user enters `7`, so

```js
var elboard = document.getElementById('board');

var userInput = prompt("How wide do you want your chessboard to be?");

var userInput = Number(userInput);

var string1 = Array(userInput + 1).join(" #")
var string2 = Array(userInput + 1).join("# ")
var newline = "\n"

var chessboard = function(i) {
  var string = i % 2 == 0 ? string1 : string2;
  console.log(string)
  elboard.appendChild(document.createTextNode(string + '\n'));
};

for (var i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
  chessboard(i);
};
```

```css
#board {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixes part of the problem. It prints chessboard but it doesn't repeat.

Comment: True, I noticed that it will print 7 lines but doesn't repeat the string 7 times

Comment: @xgrioux sorry what do you mean

Comment: If the user inputs 7 as their desired width, the chessboard has 7 new lines with the strings repeated 6 times rather than 7 times.

Comment: Perfect! I guess it was seeing the userInput as the number of indexes vs how many times I wanted it repeated- the + 1 helped with that problem.

Comment: The only thing I have a hard time grasping is the reason to put in i % 2 == 0.... what exactly is i representing? Is it the number of characters in the string?

Comment: @xgrioux that is the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) it will return 0 if the value of `i` is completely divisible by 2

Comment: Thanks Arun. I know what a modulus symbol does, I don't however understand what i stands for within the chessboard function...

Comment: @xgrioux here we have 2 types of lines... id `string1` and `string2`... now in each iteration of the loop we need to know which of the string to be used... so the simple logic here is if the value of `i` is a multiple of 2(ie, 0, 2, 4 etc) use `string1` else `string2`